# Make [users] into [members]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

It was [suggested](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21852684#21852684) in the chatroom that many of our `users` tags should be renamed to `members`. I feel, "members" makes sense, especially as we consider all the areas we cover for community building. [Neighbors](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/mowing-lawn-early-morning-on-saturday) aren't "users" of a community, but they are "members" of a community.

To me, "users" indicates someone is using software of some kind. They are "using" something to participate in the community. "Members" implies being a part of a group. You can be both a "user" and a "member", but within a community "member" is more encompassing.

---

**Proposal**

I think we can rename the following tags from "user" to "member":

1. [new-users](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-users) -> [new-members](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-members)
2. [established-users](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/established-users) -> [experienced-members](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experienced-members); This was renamed from "established" to "experienced" to remove the Stack Exchange bias associated with a specific reputation level: [Established Users](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user)
3. [inactive-users](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inactive-users) -> [inactive-members](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inactive-members)

With this rename to "members", I also propose that we synonymized all of these to the the old "users" tags. This keeps everyone on the same set of tags, but still allows people to find tags via "users" or "members" searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been completed.

- [new-users](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-users) has been renamed and synonymized to [new-members](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-members)
- [established-users](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/established-users) has been renamed and synonymized to [experienced-members](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experienced-members)
- [inactive-users](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inactive-users) has **not** been changed because there are no questions with that tag any longer.